# Locating an evasive pseudo-element

Tags: pseudo-element, devtools

From what I've seen, many (beginning) web developers have trouble placing pseudo-elements. The old trick with position:absolute and top/left etc. produces unexpected results in certain situations.

I frequently can't for the love of me find where a pseudo-element is hiding, but I know it's there somewhere. DevTools doesn't seem to help. The element seems to be rendered, there's no errors or conflicts, but it's off the viewport and is nowhere to be found. Or maybe sometimes it's hidden beneath another element (z-index issue).

Is there some method for revealing the location of sneaky pseudo-elements?